# Jumping from DSP concepts to practice...recommend books?

Tags: reference-request

I have fairly good understanding of DSP theory and algorithm design (and also MATLAB and C). What are the best books or what other advice could be given for learning how to actually implement DSP algorithms i.e. DSP programming (e.g. fixed-point/floating-point considerations etc.)

I have also considered getting a DSP evaluation board for learning purposes but am lost as to which one to get, any advice?

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/427/29

Answer (score 4):

The [USRP](https://www.ettus.com/product) with [Gnu Radio](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki) software is a good and relatively inexpensive (not that cheap, but much cheaper than almost anything else out there) DSP platform.  Gnu Radio is also open source, so if you develop something good you can submit it to the project.

Answer (score 2):

For implementing DSP algorithms in matlab I found this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1402064098) to be very useful. For practice you can start contributing to a Open Source project like [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) by implementing dsp algorithms or optimizing existing ones.