# Book recommendations on DSP, statistical SP and signal detection

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a good reference on DSP. I am a little bit more than beginner and have some experience in DPS. I think I would have to start with rather easier books where a concept of DSP is explained based on practical examples, intuitively.

Eventually I'd take more advanced books to have solid understanding of DSP, including statistical signal analysis such as power spectra, cross-spectra, coherence, autocorrelation, and cross-correlation and ultimately I'd be interested in signal, sound, noise, or speech detection.

For beginners, people recommend

- Rick Lyons' *Understanding DSP*
- Sanjit K. Mitra, *Digital Signal Processing: A Computer-Based Approach*
- [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/) - free online book

All recommendations of advanced books are by Alan V. Oppenheim's e.g.:

- Alan V. Oppenheim, Ronald W. Schafer, John R. Buck, *Discrete-Time Signal Processing*, Prentice-Hall Signal Processing Series.
- Alan V. Oppenheim, Alan S. Willsky, with S. Hamid, *Signals and Systems*, Prentice Hall

There was one more recommendation:

- John G. Proakis, Dimitris K Manolakis, *Digital Signal Processing: Principles, Algorithms and Applications*, Prentice Hall

These books are usually quite expensive which is fine but I would not like to buy something I'd be disappointed with. If you could recommend or say whether the books I listed are worth the price, I'd be grateful :)

Thanks.

---

EDIT.

I have decided to buy and go through "*Understanding Digital Signal Processing*" by Rick Lyons. I am still waiting for it but have had a chance to read through first two chapters via Kindle App. I must say I am already happy and don't regret this purchase. I'd recommend this book for all starters.

Answer (score 7):

The Proakis and Manolakis book is good if you're looking for one book.

If you're looking for depth about statistical signal processing, I recommend the series of three by Steven M. Kay:

- *Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing Volume I: Estimation Theory*
- *Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing Volume II: Detection Theory*
- *Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing Volume III: Practical Algorithm Development*

If you want some more advanced statistical signal processing books, then the ones by Harry L. van Trees might be more your style:

- *Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory (Part I)*
- *Nonlinear Modulation Theory (Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory, Part II)*
- *Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory, Radar-Sonar Signal Processing and Gaussian Signals in Noise (Part III)*
- *Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory, Optimum Array Processing (Part IV)*

Comment: Thanks. I've found the Proakis and Manolakis book in a library so I'll have a go with that one. Hopefully, it will give me decent basics to understand more complex books :)

Answer (score 4):

To the excellent recommendations so far, I would like to add two books I have found useful in understanding digital signal processing.

These are:

1) Introductory Digital Signal Processing with Computer Applications by Lynn and Fuerst

The book is very well written and makes extensive use of block diagrams that help immensely in visualising signal operations. A bit old but still useful.

2) Digital Signal Processing: A Practical Approach by Ifeachor.

This is a very good introductory book but also contains code examples in various architectures and from a wide variety of applications including the  communications, audio and biomedical domains.