# How should someone start to learn machine learning and computer vision for mobile applications?

Tags: computer-vision, machine-learning

I am very interested in learning Machine Learning and Computer Vision for mobile apps, for iOS and Android.
But I have no clue or even a slight idea on how to even begin. I know this is heavy on math and some theory I am not familiar with.

Should I use a library for this kind of thing, when I build a mobile app? Or should I do native coding? For example, to create  photo effect from a camera?
What are all things I need to know to be able to learn this?

Comment: The first part of the question can be answered, here, via some useful posts regarding [DSP Books](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22264/book-recommendations-on-dsp-statistical-sp-and-signal-detection). They are about Signal Processing but a lot of the methods can be extended to 2D as well. It's a start anyway. The second part is more technical and probably better answered at Stack Overflow (?). In general, the point is not the code, the real point is the principles behind the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For machine learning there is a very good [free MOOC on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) that can give you the basics of machine learning, with a lot of examples. Prerequisites are basic maths and computer programming comprehension.

For computer vision I would advise you to first learn about DSP in general.
[This book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8131764362) has had great reviews everywhere and although I haven't read it yet, I'm pretty sure it's a good start in the vast area of signal processing. There is also an online book, [The Scientist & Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm), with plenty of information on digital filtering.

Once you have understood the fundamental theory of Machine Learning and DSP, you can start learning programming in C++. One very famous library for computer vision is [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). You will be able to find many tutorials online.

Comment: I am used in Python. Can i use python for computer vision? And somehow use Python scripts with IOS app?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest [Professor Hoff](http://inside.mines.edu/~whoff/) and [Professor Mubarak](http://crcv.ucf.edu/people/faculty/shah.php)'s great video lectures which are freely accessible [here](http://inside.mines.edu/~whoff/) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=715uLCHt4jE).