# A DSP simple book/reference?

Tags: reference-request

I have some basic maths skill up to derivatives. 
I ask you if you know any simple/concise book that can introduce me to DSP world. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend the following two books (which are free!):

- [Introduction to Signal Processing](http://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/intro2sp/) by S.J. Orfanidis
- [Signal Processing for Communications](http://www.sp4comm.org/getit.html) by P. Prandoni and M. Vetterli

Also take a look at the answers to [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/427/what-resources-are-recommended-for-an-introduction-to-dsp).

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that the best book I found was

- [Understanding Digital Signal Processing by Richard G. Lyons](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0137027419)

It help me a lot, and dont need to understand complex math :)