# Beginner's Books

Tags: image-processing, dsp-core

I come from a background of computer science and I got interested in image processing but it requires a lot of signal processing, so could someone provide me a good beginner's book, that maybe first year college/uni students use?

I understand that dsp is crucial for image processing, so I focus on the first thing for now.

Thanks,

Comment: See this recent question: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18564/a-dsp-simple-book-reference

Answer (score -1):

Discrete time signal processing - Oppenheim and Schafer.

Has excellent notation and simple explanation

Comment: Why the downvote?!!