# How to Design a Pre-emphasis filter knowing the gain, a zero and a pole?

Tags: filters, filter-design, finite-impulse-response, highpass-filter, frequency-modulation

I am simulating an FM radio signal in order to use it as a waveform in passive radar; for this purpose I'm following an article:
[Analysis and Emulation of FM Radio Signals for Passive Radar](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4161478/)

In a certain step, I need to design an emphasis filter for the rdiophonic signal, the filter has these characteristics:

- a gain of -5.4 dB ?(is it the gain at half of sampling frequency?)
- a zero imposed by international standards (can't find the zero)and a pole - to make it
  physically realizable - at 40 kHz. I know the response function of the Pre-emphasis filter

$$ H(j \omega) = 1 + \frac{j \omega}{\omega_0} $$

or in z domain:

$$H(z) = 1-B \cdot z $$

, can't understand where is the pole? 
Of course i will use a FIR filter ,but how to find the coefficient $B$.

thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, these filters were implemented as analog filters, and they are different from the usual discrete-time first-order FIR pre-emphasis filter used in speech processing.

The transfer function of such an analog pre-emphasis filter is

$$H(s)=g\frac{1+s\tau_1}{1+s\tau_2},\qquad\tau_1\gt\tau_2,\tag{1}$$

where $g$ is the DC gain, and $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are two time constants determining the locations of the zero and the pole:

$$s_0=-\frac{1}{\tau_1}\\s_{\infty}=-\frac{1}{\tau_2}\tag{2}$$

If the pole (or the zero) are given in terms of frequencies $f_i$, then the following relation holds:

$$\tau_i=\frac{1}{2\pi f_i},\qquad i\in\{1,2\}\tag{3}$$

So for a given frequency $f_i$ you can use $(3)$ to determine the corresponding time constant, from which you obtain the desired transfer function $(1)$.

If you want to implement that filter in discrete time, the most common option is to use the [bilinear transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform):

$$s=\frac{2}{T}\frac{z-1}{z+1}\tag{4}$$

where $T$ is the sampling period, i.e., the inverse of the sampling frequency. Note that $(2)$ is the bilinear transform without pre-warping, which means that the frequency axis will be warped, so neither the pole frequency nor the zero frequency of the analog filter will be exactly realized in the discrete-time domain. You can pre-warp the analog frequencies (or time constants) to make sure that the resulting discrete-time filter has the desired pole and zero frequencies. In order to realize a (pole or zero) frequency $f_i$ in the discrete-time domain, you need to use the following time constant in the analog filter transfer function $(1)$:

$$\tau_i=\frac{T}{2\tan\left(\frac{\pi f_i}{f_s}\right)}\tag{5}$$

where $f_s=1/T$ is the sampling frequency.

You can find more information on pre-warping in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/22770/4298).

Comment: To see an implementation of this, look at the comments and the function I implemented at the end of this file: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-analog/python/analog/fm_emph.py

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the  link ! just to say that from the literrature I read,  the pre-emphasis filter is designed  with a constant time fixed at the value of 50micros or (75microsec) according to the region you are. I will read more deeply your response and try to undestand some new concepts for me !

Comment: Hello ! the code  @Andy Walls is really helpful for implementing in matlab the pre-emphasis filter  I'v 2 issues: don't understand the calculation of the gain at dc (line 295), for me I would calculate the final gain as g*bo (g of eq1) ,g equal to -5.4dB (from my specifications). the 2nd issue: since the pole is at 40khz >fs/2 (24khz) should I do a conversion of sampling rate or take it as 0.925*fs/2.just to say that the final FM complex envelop should have a sampling rate of 200 khz according to literarture. I've an audio signal of 48khz sample rate .

Comment: ...after calculation of z1, p1 and bo as in the code , I use the bilinear transformation of matlab to make  the coversion to digital, but the result is bad since I obtain an horizontal line for the magnitude trasform at -17dB. sure I'm missing something, thanks in advance ,for your comments

Comment: here is the bilinear transformation of matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/bilinear.html

Answer (score 1):

I want to post the code of the pre-emphasis filter, a matlab transtlation od the code shared by Andy Walls. I think it works perfectly,well I think...

```
%This code is a succint translation to matlab of the code shared by Andy Walls
%pre-emphasis filter with a gain of -5.4dB, a pole at 40khZ and a constant
%time of 50 µs

%---------Specifications---------------------------------------------------

fs=48000;
to=50e-6;
w_cl=1/to;
f_cl=w_cl/(2*pi);
f_ch=40e3;
g_dc=10^(-5.4/20);

if f_ch >= fs/2 % In my case f_ch=40000 hZ
    f_ch=0.925*fs/2;
end 

w_ch=2*pi*f_ch;

%------use of bilinear transformation for disigning digital filter---------

%Convert digitial specifications into the analog domain, by prewarping
% digital frequency specifications into analog frequencies.

w_cla = (2*fs)*tan(w_cl/(2*fs));
w_cha = (2*fs)*tan(w_ch/(2*fs));

%---------------------Calculation Of poles and zeros for digital filter
%------using the bilinear transformation -----------------------------------

% H(z) = H(s)|s = (2/T)(1-z^-1)/(1+z^-1)
kl=-w_cla/(2*fs);
kh=-w_cha/(2*fs);
z1 = (1.0 + kl) / (1.0 - kl);
p1 = (1.0 + kh) / (1.0 - kh);
b0 = (1.0 - kl) / (1.0 - kh);

%Since  this filter  has a Dc gain of -5.4 dB gain 
% i have to correct with a gain g given as follows

g=(abs(1.0-p1)/(bo*abs(1-z1)))*g_dc;
b=[g*bo -g*bo*z1];
a=[1 -p1];
freqz(b,a);
```