# When do we have a minimum phase couple

Tags: poles-zeros

I am a DSP newbie and I am really confused after reading Chapter two of

"An Introduction to Digital Signal Processing by J. H. Karl".

On page 32, first paragraph, the book defines a minimum phase couplet as one with zeros OUTSIDE the unit circle of the z-plane. But I have read everywhere else that a minimum phase system has all zeros and poles INSIDE the unit circle.

Is this a contradiction? When do we have a  minimum phase couplet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book uses the convention that $Z$ represents a unit delay (this is explained on [this page](https://books.google.nl/books/reader?id=9Dv1PClLZWIC&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&source=gbs_atb&pg=GBS.PA28)). The more common convention is to denote the unit delay by $z^{-1}$. Consequently, minimum-phase systems have all their zeros *inside* the unit circle of the $z$-plane, but *outside* the unit circle of the $Z$-plane.

Comment: Wonderful. Thanks a lot. I have spent two days trying to find why but did not consider the convention used by the book. I was going to drop the book for a modern alternative but I think I might crack on with it if I cannot find an alternative. Thanks a lot for saving me.

Comment: @Chika: Have a look at [this answer](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18564/a-dsp-simple-book-reference/18568#18568) for two other great (and free) DSP books.

Comment: @Chika you shall better drop the book anyway, what is the meaning of learning everthing with an opposite convention and then trying to map everything back to the other?

Comment: @Fat32 Yeah good point, am gonna have to let it go. I also struggle with the some of the questions at the end of the chapters; with no way to check my answer since there are no solutions and the question seems to require Math that the chapters did not mention.