# DSP Book with More Applications

Tags: digital-filters

The process of my DSP class used the Oppenheimer DSP book as text. Although I can easily understand the math in the book, I found it lack examples and applications, hence I still cannot build a picture how people actually use those under different circumstances. Can someone recommend me a DSP book that contains more practical examples and applications more than "This example uses the mathematical formula above to derive some numbers from some numbers"? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I could only repeat [this answer of mine](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/18568/4298).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully you'll get a bunch of answers here from the very general to the super specific. I'll put in my two cents here.

The recommendations I would make are from the field of radar and communication systems. These systems tend to exercise almost all aspects of signal processing:

1. Signal generation and mixing
2. Sampling, decimating/upsampling
3. Signal conditioning
4. General filter design and implementation
5. Detection theory
6. Target/observable tracking
7. Advanced techniques such as eigen-decomposition and super-resolution

Unfortunately books in the radar and communications fields are not free, but in my opinion are worth their asking price (as far as texts are concerned).

### Bassem Mahafza: Radar System Analysis and Design using MATLAB, Chapman & Hall

This book is an awesome treatment of many of the aspects of a radar/comms system. As the title suggests, buying this book gives you access to all of the MATLAB functions provided by the author. As you work through the theory of the book, many sections have accompanying examples that you can play with allowing you to both see implementation details and visuals.

### Merril I. Skolnik: Radar Handbook, Third Edition, McGraw-Hill

This book is a very large collection of different authors' work. It covers almost everything you can imagine about signal processing in a radar system. Theory, practicalities, and implementation specifics are all covered here. This book is to be used as a reference for applications and does not really contain examples of how to code certain things.

### Harry L. Van Trees: Optimum Array Processing: Part IV of Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory, Wiley & Sons

This one is dense and I would consider to be the more hardcore of the three. This text exposes to you a bunch of different techniques in signal processing when you have access to an antenna array, which would not be possible otherwise. Applications include radar, astronomy, communications, seismology, medical diagnosis, etc.

I could list many more but these are the three that come to mind that are a good mix of theory, applications of that theory, and examples.

Answer (score 2):

The book:

[Richard G. Lyons  (Editor), *Streamlining Digital Signal Processing: A Tricks of the Trade Guidebook 2nd Edition*,  Wiley-IEEE Press; 2nd edition (July 2, 2012)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118278380)

is a compendium of short application-specific signal processing algorithms.

**Disclaimer:** I wrote one of the chapters with Eric Jacobsen, but I do not benefit monetarily from the sales of the book.