# Digital Signal Processing DSP Overview study documents

Tags: self-study

Well, I couldn't find better expression to say what I want :(

I'm looking for a DSP study source, that doesn't dive too deep, and covers "all" or most of DSP topics, I just want to have an overview of it, then, as a next step, it will be easier to go deeper.

A PDF file, an online file, video course, tutorial, ... I french we say "Résumé de cours" or "course summary" but it didn't give me what I expected!

Plz, for those having no answer, plz, tell me how to ask about it and google it

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'd suggest this: https://jackschaedler.github.io/circles-sines-signals/

Comment: digital-signal-processing-coursera

Comment: Could your question be a duplicate of [this one](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/427/what-resources-are-recommended-for-an-introduction-to-dsp/428#428) ?

Answer (score 3):

There are some books (some free) that cover most DSP topics with a claim of easy approach, probably they cover the most important fundamentals:

1- Understanding Digital Signal Processing_R.Lyons

2- Scientist and Engineer's guide to DSP_S.W.Smith ([free from web](http://www.dspguide.com/))

3- Signal Processing First_McClellan

Comment: i sorta remember when the #3 came out (i think it was ca. 1990 when i was teaching at U of Southern Maine).  i am *not* sure i agree with the premise (i sorta like Oppenheim's *Signals and Systems* approach that develops continuous and discrete-time LTI principles together in parallel, otherwise it's all MATLAB and i would like to see some early pedagogical use of circuits and op-amps in the lab.)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I agree with you. I've sorta seen it quite recently, and I found it a pretty interesting but not a very *serious* (in the formality of electrical engineering sense) introduction to DSP . But I thought the OP wanted some broad and easy going materials (books) so I sorta included it. PS: Originally I hated Oppenheim's Signals&Systems book as a student. It's the DTSP which made me like the subject and the author. Later I found Signals&Systems very useful !

Comment: I helped Rick by doing some proof-reading for him on a couple of editions of #1.  I found it to be a refreshing take on O&S and the lads doing things "more rigorously".

Comment: @PeterK That's really a nice book. The best seller of its kind on Amazon. DSP is a strange subject; one has quite different views on it before and after "Understanding" it. So Rick L. does an interesting job there :-)