# How to Improve Signal Processing Skills?

Tags: dsp-core, self-study

I've heard that signal processing is fundamental field that can be applied to many other fields (MRI, EEG, audio, speech recognition, communication even to economics)

So, I want to contribute myself to studying this field deeply.

I already took Signals and systems and DSP, and also in this semester, I'm taking Statistical Signal Processing.

This may be stupid question
But, I cannot form any idea of how I can improve and study signal processing.
Taking a theoretical theory is not enough to get the concept.
And even if I learned some basics, I still don't know what signal processing is in general.
Constructing a filter or classifier is main goal of signal processing?

Could you share the general insight and recommend the method I can follow?

Comment: Perhaps the way the question is phrased is primarily opinion based (?). I think that the "I still don't know what signal processing is in general", "Is constructing a filter or classifier DSP?" questions should feature more prominently. Also, is there a particular background you are coming from? What would you use DSP for? (Biomedical signals, vibration analysis, audio....other?)

Comment: By studying "Understanding Digital Signal Processing" book.

Comment: @JHK, Could you mark an answer or comment what is missing?

Answer (score 2):

at the beginning, it's suggested to follow systematic courses, and then you can go further by yourself.

I suggest, that you follow such courses here http://nptel.ac.in/course.php  just try to follow it step by step in order to understand the concept. then you can read books and watch videos in Edx and Coursera just to improve your level.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways is to hang out on this community.
Read questions and answers.
Try to replicate results on answers.

Once you have more knowledge, try answering questions of others.
If you encounter a question on a field you don't know, find resources to read about it until you can answer the question (Assuming it is not deep and requires deep knowledge).

Other classic approaches would be books.
Yet, I recommend Hand On approach.
Namely if you read a book, choose those which has code inside them to replicate results and have better understanding of real world models.

You may even look for some courses on [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/):

1. [Digital Signal Processing](https://www.coursera.org/learn/dsp).
2. [Audio Signal Processing for Music Applications](https://www.coursera.org/learn/audio-signal-processing).
3. [Fundamentals of Digital Image and Video Processing](https://www.coursera.org/learn/digital).

There are few options on [edX](https://www.edx.org) as well:

1. [Discrete Time Signal Processing](https://www.edx.org/course/discrete-time-signal-processing-mitx-6-341x-1).
2. [Signals and Systems, Part 1](https://www.edx.org/course/signals-and-systems-part-1-1).
3. [Signals and Systems, Part 2](https://www.edx.org/course/signals-systems-part-2-iitbombayx-ee210-2x-3).
4. [Discrete Time Signals and Systems, Part 1: Time Domain](https://www.edx.org/course/discrete-time-signals-systems-part-1-ricex-elec301-1x).
5. [Discrete Time Signals and Systems, Part 2: Frequency Domain](https://www.edx.org/course/discrete-time-signals-systems-part-2-ricex-elec301-2x).

For more classic recommendation you may refer to [What Resources Are Recommended for an Introduction to Signal Processing (DSP)?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/427)

Enjoy the ride!

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinion based answer.  Living creates its own priorities. The majority of human kind need to earn a living.  Get a paying job in a DSP area of some company or organization that has DSP as core competency.  In most cases, the DSP you will practice will have some social/commercial purpose. The specific kind of processing you do will align along the activities of the entity that employs you.  You will have "customers" that use Signal Processing in some manner.  You will get to understand what the needs and problems of these "customers" are and will work towards DSP solutions to their needs and problems.  You will learn what social/economic/cognitive constraints they have and incorporate them into your DSP solutions.  You might get very good at this and end up not doing any direct DSP in the long term.  None of this will necessarily make you happy.